# How to import CSS files to React JS application?

Tags: css, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am creating an application, created multiple CSS files but those are not able to import.

I tried by installing css-loader and style-loader. But it doesn't help

Please look below picture, I have **Burger.css** file. but it not visible to import

[image]

Comment: Does your `import classess from './Layout.css'` works ? Because I don't think you can do that. Usually you will import a css file as follow : `import './Layout.css'` and it will be applied to you code.

Comment: No, it is also not working @QuentinGrisel

Comment: What happens if you actually type out the full name, `../Burger/BurgerIngredient/Burger.css`?  Is there an error message?

Answer (score 1):

VS Code by default doesn't autocomplete all file types. If you write **import ./Burger/Burger.css** or **import ./Burger/BurgerIngredient/BurgerIngredient.css** in your Layout.js file, your css files will be loaded fine.

If you want to use autocomplete for all files in VS Code, you can use this extension.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ionutvmi.path-autocomplete

Without Extension

[image: Without Extension]

With Extension

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok since you confirmed that your `./Layout.css` import does not work, you should not name your import when it's about a css file. Doing :

`import './myFile.css';`

is enough to apply your css.

Note that css is global in React, so you might want to use `styled component` or encapsulate your css to prevent side effect on other components).

Now, if you really want to add style the way you tried to, there is the `style` attribute which accepts an object. So you could do:

`<div style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>Hello World !</div>`

Note that the css properties are written in **camelCase**.

Comment: I think he is trying to use CSS modules here in his css import. https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-1-need/

Answer (score 0):

Your file structure appears to me to be...

```
-Burger
--BurgerIngredient
----Burger.css
--Layout
----Layout.css
```

Your primary application, from what it appears here, is in `/Burger`.  Considering that, when you type import, you see the dropdown appear, showing helpful suggestions, and it lists...

```
-../Burger/BurgerIngredient/...
```

As a possible, valid location.  In that case, why don't we try importing css, by typing out...

```
import burgercss from '../Burger/BurgerIngredient/Burger.css';
```

Note, for instance, `Burger.css` wouldn't show up until you select `BurgerIngredient`, because that's its conntaining folder.